# What is the date today vs What date is today

Tags: syntactic-analysis, questions

What is the difference between

**What is the date today?**

and

**What date is today?**

I don't understand why the position of the verb "is" changes and what it means

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your second example is unusual, so it would be helpful if you could [edit] your post to indicate where you have heard these formulations, and what any initial research has shown you. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: The second formulation is ungrammatical. The closest correct formulation would be to ask *"what date is **it** today?"* - with "it" referring implicitly to "the date" (which is an unstated clause). In full, the question would be *"what date is the date today?"* or *"what date is today's date?"*

Comment: February 8th, 2021.

Comment: I'll note that "What day is today?" would not be unusual in conversation.

Comment: Many idioms do employ a "non-referential subject" as in "It is raining", "It is three o'clock". Hence the inclusion of  "it" while of doubtful necessity from a grammatical point of view, is part of the usual idiom.

Comment: Note that _What day of the week is today?_ or _What day of the month is Tuesday?_ are perfectly normal. Dummy _it_'s are OK, too, but not needed. Another case of user choice.

Comment: It's like asking 'time'. People often ask, "What's the time now?" or just "What is the time?" It may not be incorrect, but I have been taught at school "What time is now?"/ What time is it now?". Some people ask "What time is it?" Isn't it like the way 'day' is dealt with?